# Iterating over a list of Strings in C++, what's going wrong?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I'm trying to print out a list of strings thus:

```
std::list<String> const &prms = (*iter)->getParams();
std::list<String>::const_iterator i;
for(i = prms.begin(); i != prms.end(); ++i){
  log.debug("  Param: %s",*i);
}
```

But my program crashes saying `Illegal Instruction`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Capital String - what class is that, the C++/CLI one? Or do you mean std::string? If so, you want `i->c_str()` for the output I think, assuming debug accepts char*.

Comment: Coming from Java, C++ confuses the hell out of me sometimes...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`*i` is a `String`, not a `char *`. If `log.debug()` is a function of the `printf` family, you want a zero-terminated string. Depending on how your `String` class is implemented you might have a function that returns a `const char *`.

For example with `std::string` that function is **`c_str`**:

```
for(std::list<std::string>::const_iterator i = my_list.begin(); i != my_list.end(); ++i)
{
     printf("%s\n", i->c_str());
}
```

Comment: You are correct in that the problem is it is not a `char *`, it's actually a proprietary `String` class, and I've now sorted the problem.